# meaning of the phrase "though it may be"?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/k7dTDjRnBqU). It is at around 5 minute and 8 second. Here is the context:

> Human beings, regrettable **though it may be**, are inherently vicious, and have to be restrained from their viciousness.

Would it mean the same if the host said it this way?

> Human beings, though it is regrettable, are inherently vicious, and have to restrained from their vicikusness.

If he could, then why did he use *may be*?

Comment: As a footnote, this expression is often worded as: _regrettable **as** it may be_, but I don’t think the meaning changes when someone uses _though_ instead of _as_.

Comment: What does "as it may be" mean? There are no, it seems, any entry in dictionary of this phrase.

Comment: Dmytro: Try looking up _as it were_.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope - Try looking up ["Be that as it may"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/be-that-as-it-may).  *Be that as it may* or *though/as it may be* are idiomatic phrases that mean something "regardless of whether it is good or bad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**regrettable though it (may) be** is a clause of concession with the subject complement fronted for emphasis.

You can move such a clause around since it relates to the predication of the main clause, not to any one constituent:

> The price, regrettable as it is, is over $10,000.
>
> Regrettable as it is, the price is over $10,000.
>
> The price is over $10,000, regrettable as it is.

Compare:

> The price, sad to say, is over $10,000.
>
> Sad to say, the price is over $10,000.
>
> The price is over $10K, sad to say.

P.S. Clauses of concession [historically were marked by the subjunctive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22regrettable%20though%20it%20be%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) (**regrettable though it be**) and **may be** could be a periphrastic substitute for subjunctive **be**,  use of which has been on the decline.